# Implementing Google AdMob to UIWebview app

Tags: ios, webview, xcode5, admob, tabbar

I'm trying to learn the best way of implementing Google's AdMob to my app I did it once but wasn't sure it was the right way so I'm trying to make sure it is. I would just like to know where in this line of code do I need to put the code for Google AdMob?

Here is what I am working with:

```
//  D3@TH's Creations
//
//  Created by D3@TH on 5/16/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 D3@TH. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://sample.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Just to let some people know so they don't get confused sample.com is not my site I removed my site because of advertising rules. I'm also making a Tab Bar WebView app.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this example from te google developers page. https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?hl=nl#ios